# Can't create Xcode Cloud flow from a Github.com repository

Tags: ios, xcode, github, cloud

Since Xcode Cloud was launched last year I'd been able to connect from the Xcode wizard to my Github.com account and the CI worked like a charm, however today I'd been trying to create an Xcode Cloud for a new app and it doesn't finish the wizard flow throwing an error

**Connecting Xcode Cloud with your source control provider was incomplete.
Repository not accessible**

[image]

On the GitHub.com side everything seems to be working, did tried this from 2 different computers with the same results, has anyone else gone through this issue?, is there a solution for this or filing a radar to Apple is the only option here?.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did it fix automatically, or did you have to do something?

Comment: Same here with self-hosted gitlab 

Comment: Apple has fixed the issue. It's working again.

Comment: So far didn't find a suitable solution, did removed the Xcode Cloud CI from that given project, if there is a fix (cause it obviously was a platform issue!), I'll try it again! thanks @Apoc

Comment: @Apoc Tenant68's answer worked for me for a self-hosted Gitlab repo.

Comment: @Isuru Thank you for mentioning it. In my case Apple fixed something in the background. It worked some hours later for me without any doing as I wrote above. But turning it off and on again is always good advice .

Comment: still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue as I had two account connected in the Team for signing in capabilities.

my solution, remove other account and keep main account for Xcode Cloud.

-Tenant

Comment: to complete the above solution my second line was "Request for another user".         and not "Repository not accessible".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To clarify on how I fixed this: I went to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts and removed all of the Developer accounts that were not the account I was authorizing for Xcode Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as I have two developer accounts - a work account and a personal account. The issue arose when the signing certificate used in the project in Xcode did not match the App Store Connect account that was signed in.

Check your signing certificate / team in Xcode and that you are logged into App Store Connect with the correct details.